# Photoshop - finding a font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I don't know if any of you had this problem, I'm using photoshop CS3,
And sometimes in order to choose a font quickly, while the text tool is selected, I click on the text field that shows the currently selected font, then I type the name of the font I want to use, most of the times it works just fine and finds the font I want,

I just bought a package of fonts, they all begin with this "EFT" and when I type that in photoshop, it will not find any of them, but only select a different font.

The fonts do show on the list when I open it and I can select them manually, but it gets annoying when you have more than 1,000 fonts installed.

Do you have any idea what I could do to solve the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have any idea what I could do to solve the issue?

Don't install 1000 fonts.

For starters, if you bought a package of 1000 fonts, they're likely not great fonts to begin with.

Secondly, no one needs 1000 fonts. 100 is kinda crazy.

Invest some time into figuring out your core set of typefaces. Most good designers work with maybe 10-20 a majority of the time, and add the occasional one-off per project or what have you. Sorting through 1000 fonts every time you work on a project is just a giant waste of time and energy.

Comment: True, still though, your answer did not solve the issue, I'll have the exact same issue if I'll have 20 fonts as well.

Comment: "I can select them manually, but it gets annoying when you have more than 1,000 fonts installed." = I think that would solve that part of the issue. Can you tell us more about the fonts? It could be that they just aren't well made fonts and perhaps their font names are wonky.

Comment: Yep it would solve this part, I'm still used to work that way and it would still interrupt me to select them manually. one of the fonts is named "EFT_Paalul Bold" It's an hebrew font, *just letting you know, all of the other hebrew fonts I have are working just fine, only these with the EFT in the beginning are problematic

Comment: So in the font menu, it's named "EFT_..."? Wild guess, but could there be some non-roman characters in that name that aren't rendering given it's a Hebrew font?

Comment: In the font menu it's named as I wrote before "EFT_Paalul Bold" exactly like the file name, all english letters, nothing else.

Comment: And yea it's really weird. I don't see anything different than other fonts, I checked the file names, the font names, they look exactly like others that does work, maybe the underscore is the problem? or caps at the beginning? if so, is it even possible to rename a font?

Comment: If it's the same as the file name, perhaps the font doesn't have a proper font name embedded. You could try editing it in something like FontForge, though note that it could make your document incompatible with the fonts your printer might be using.

Answer (score 0):

Font name started with EFT? Not file name, but font name you need to typing.
Font name and file name are different things.

Comment: The font name is starting with EFT, I know that these are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the "EFT" and just type the actual name of the font. It's possible that the internal font name doesn't contain the EFT prefix, so Photoshop doesn't "see" it when you type. DA01's advice is sound, though. Keep your 1,000 fonts in a separate folder, not installed. You'll see better performance from Photoshop and you won't have to sift through all those fonts. An inexpensive font manager like [TypeDNA](http://www.typedna.com/) will allow you to browse more efficiently, help you select fonts that work well together and activate them only when you actually need them.